# how to read javascripts values and send them as c# variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdown as follows:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("studentList", myModel.GetMyList())
```

I have a variable that stores the selected value in javeascript.

```
 userID = $("#studentList> option:selected").attr("value")
```

However, I need to send the seleted value in c# to my controller.  How can I achive that?

How do I read the selected value from the dropdown in c# or how can I "translate" the javascript value in c# varaiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "Simple", Create a HiddenField, and store the selected values in that, before post your data to server.

to get the selected values try something like that:

```
var myValues= new Array();
$("#studentList> option:selected").each(function(){
    myValues.push($(this).attr('value'));
})

$('#hiddenField').attr('value', myValues.join(','));
```

On then server-side, just have to split the string to get the values

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the value in a hidden field via JS

```
<%=Html.Hidden("student", "none")%>
```

Then access the value of the hidden field from c#

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox selected value should already be sent over to the server as long as its in the form. Is there a reason that isn't sufficient?